# Frederic Paul Schuller QFT notes

Tags: quantum-field-theory, education, specific-reference

I have heard that Fredric Paul schuller gave a lecture on Quantum field theory once. Can someone provide me with the lecture notes of that course?

Comment: Link to video lectures?

Comment: I don't have the link but someone in the YouTube comment section mentioned it.

Comment: I don't think the QFT video lectures are public, atleast for now. That's what he says in an interview.